# How to recover a deleted (Jupyter Notebook) code in Visual Studio Code? CTRL + Z doest work

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidentally deleted a piece of code on `Visual Studio Code`. I haven't closed visual studio yet.

`CTRL + Z` doesn't work. `Edit + Undo` doesn't work either. The variables are still stored.
It was accidental. I just happen to close a jupyter notebook box

Any idea how I can recover thank you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question, happens to most of us when working longer and not paying attention.
Vscode starting from a specific version does internal management of your code ([March 2020 release](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_44)). This feature is called `timeline`.

What to do: 
`Right click on your .ipynb file` > `Open Timeline` >  `Restore contents` on a specific version of your file.

Also, before restoring, would suggest that you check out the version you're going to restore by comparing it with the current one.

Note: This does not require the git repository to be active at the time of the incident. As this is what Vscode is technically doing by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot get it back if you have not backed up.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to recover the deleted code if `CTRL +Z` doesn't work.

You can click right on the `.ipynb` script, open chronology then go to your last changes and click on it. You will then see the deleted part.